# Do the blue birds in Angry Birds speak French?

Tags: angry-birds

When you launch them, the blue birds say something that sounds very much like *Salut les amis!* in French (*Hello friends!*). Furthermore, other bird screams sound like *Oui!* (*Yes!*), though this is arguably more of a coincidence.

I wonder if the developers at Rovio started from samples in French and modified their pitch in order to use them in the game. Can anyone (in)validate that?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can find, the wholly Finnish game developer has never said anything about the bird sounds, let alone their alleged Frenchiness.  Any answer beyond this would be opinion and thus not a proper answer for this site, unless one of the 10 or so people from the original development team can give a definitive answer followed by "I know cuz I was there."